# Best way to get large query result to template in Flask

Tags: python, sql, json, flask, chunking

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a large query which I have converted to a JSON string constructed from a list of lists of about 500000+ entries to a template.  The current way I'm doing it worked for smaller objects:

```
return render_template('/dataprocessing.html', data=json.dumps(result))
```

Where *data=json.dumps(result)* is how I pass the large JSON string to the template. However, the size of this string stored in the client greatly slows down my application. I also know that there is another way to pass it through cookies, but that is worse than this method and won't work for larger sizes.

What my application does is it renders a large amount of data from a database through a SQL query. I want to visualize this data in a template by stepping through this data row-by-row and creating DOM elements representing these rows.

I've been searching for hours and trying to implement solutions to this with little success so if anybody could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

### One solution I had in mind is chunking up the data and sending one chunk at a time from the view to the template. I would then send the next chunk when we step to the last row of the current chunk inside of the template. AND would I do this through an AJAX call? (I'm fairly new to web dev).

Answer (score 1):

This is a ton of data to pass into the browser, and would choke any user's computer. For example, imagine if Google showed 100,000 results instead of just 10 or 20 -- the searches would be incredibly slow to render. If you want to visualize the data, I think you would probably want to pre-aggregate it before sending it the template so it is 'graph-ready'. Let's take a trivial example:

```
id,name,publisher
1,war and peace,penguin
2,romeo and juliet,harper
3,the trial, penguin
```

You might wnt to pass it into your template pre-aggregated, such as:

```
[
  {
    "publisher": "penguin",
    "count": 2,
    "items": ["war and peace", "the trial"]
  },
  {
    "publisher": "haper",
    "count": 1,
    "items": ["romeo and juliet"]
  }
]
```

In this way, you'd process your data **before** it is sent to your template, and in the above example, could do something like a Bar Graph and onHover you display the books that it has (or perhaps the top 5 -- most of the data will be somehow truncated in the webview if there is a ton of it).